# MS Excel: how to use a (random) number as row number in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1 contains a combinations of numbers from 1 to 18 without duplications, like this:

| 1 | Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Sheet2 contains x (e.g.: 10) random numbers from 2 to 817 (the number of rows in Sheet1, header excluded), like this:

| Random number | Sheet1.Col A | Sheet1.Col B | Sheet1.Col C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211 |  |  |  |
| 354 |  |  |  |
| 807 |  |  |  |
| 198 |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I need: I would like to use the random generated number as row number to be used to get the relative Sheet1 values and put them in Sheet2 in the relative column...
E.g.: in the last row of Sheet2 I would like to have 1,2 and 7 in the second, third and fourth column.
I hope it's clear :)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use XLOOKUP to find the row in Sheet1. Put this in under the Sheet1.ColA header in the first row in Sheet2:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,SEQUENCE(816),Sheet1!$A$2:$C$817)
```

Then drag it down to the last row in Sheet2.

Simplified example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(LEFT(B$1,FIND(".",B$1)-1)&"!"&RIGHT(B$1,LEN(B$1)-FIND(" ",B$1))&$A2)
```

[image]

[image]